# C# Maintain Current Focus on Page Update

Tags: c#, focus

I have a web page that requires several user inputs.  After each update though the page jumps back to the top making the user have to scroll down to reach the input fields again.  I would like the page to maintain the focus it has on each update.  If that's not possible I would like to at least jump to the top of the table of inputs after each update.  I am using:

```
SetFocus(<tag name>)
```

But it is not working.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: You might want to retain the scroll after browser refresh I guess - http://worthposting.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/retain-scroll-position-after-browser-refresh/

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using C#, so if you are using ASP.NET as well, you can try setting the [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx) property of System.Web.UI.Page to true.  This will enable the page to return to the position it was in prior to the postback.

Comment: I was unaware of this...  I worked with ASP.NET a few years back and did not have any issues, so this is good to know.  Thanks.